# Метод класса через пременную

Tags: php

Доброй ночи !

Совсем запутался.

Есть класс:

```
 class Test {

    function index() {      
        echo 'Test-index';          
    }

    function test() {
        echo 'Test-test';
    }

 }
```

и функция

```
 function load($class, $method) {

 //допустим $class = 'Test', $method = 'index'  ($method = 'index()' тоже пробовал)

     $test = new $class;

  // $test->index() работает
     $test->$method; // не работает Undefined property: Test::$index
 }
```

Как же его можно корректно вызвать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно вы имели введу это:

```
class Test {
  public function testMethod() {
    echo 'called!';
  }
}

$t = new Test();
$methodName = 'testMethod';
$t->$methodName();
```

---

Если-же нет - такого рода поведение не стандартно для PHP, для того, что-бы иметь возможность так делать нужно сохранять в поле класса анонимную функцию, пример (PHP 5.3+):

```
class Test {
    public $testPropertyMethod;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->testPropertyMethod = function() {
            echo 'Hello closure';
        };
    }
}

$t = new Test();
$fieldName = 'testPropertyMethod';
$func = $t->$fieldName;
$func();
```

Но здесь есть одно но - применив такой подход вызов кода вида:

```
$t->$fieldName(); // выбросит ошибку
```

Для того, что-бы вызов корректно работал и в таком случае, необходимо определить (звучит тупо, но не я это придумал) "волшебный" метод __call в нашем классе, что-то типа:

```
public function __call( $methodName, $arguments ) {
  $func = $this->$methodName;
  return call_user_func_array($func, $arguments);
}
```

Теперь абсолютно все будет работать именно так, как положено.

PS: Небольшая справка: в анонимных функциях не доступен $this (хотя при необходимости, естественно, мы можем передать его самостоятельно).

Comment: Вот то что нужно, $t->$methodName(); работает как мне надо. Не заметил, что скобки то не поставил :). Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $test->$method();
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно ! Просто к сожалению, за правильный могу принять лишь 1. :(

Comment: @FLK - интересная особенность php 5.4 была еще начиная с четвертой версии :D

В четвертой конструкторы определялись именно так, потом придумали __construct, но старый подход поддерживается и дальше для совместимости